# I don't understand the reason reg. expression does not work

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some java script code running on my chrome browser. While writing react code I used:

```
const dateRegExp = /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[.\d*]?/;
console.log('dateRegExp.test('+ x +') = ' + dateRegExp.test(x));
console.log('dateRegExp.test('+ y +') = ' + dateRegExp.test(y));
```

But I am getting:

```
dateRegExp.test('1995-10-22 12:21:31') = false

dateRegExp.test('1993-12-21 10:22:33.1') = true
```

I need to be true for both cases. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: `/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[.\d*]?/.test('1995-10-22 12:21:31')` returns `true`

Comment: Cannot reproduce what you've described in this [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gmRGFG/1). While you might need to re-visit what you actually think is happening with your last character set, both strings should match the pattern you've provided.

Comment: Both values return `true` here.

Comment: Yet, while executed on my Chrome browser, they do not

Comment: [Both return true in Chrome](https://jsbin.com/nijefoz/edit?js,console)

Comment: I think I found the error: If I use dateRegExp.test(..) the problem persist. But if I use the / ... /.test(..) it works.. I do not why

Comment: Look at the JSBin again - I'm using exactly your code there and both times it's returning `true`. You are not giving us the correct issue here.

Comment: Estrange, that behavior happens in my Linux Chrome browser. I don't see what else can I give!

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga: Are you sure `global` flag is not being used in your regex. If you're `g` then you will run into this issue.

Comment: no global, ... but it seems  I needed to escape . also. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue rests in `[.\d*]?` because it translates to "optionally exactly match one of the following: `.` (literal period), `\d` (any digit), `*` (literal asterisk).

At minimum you want:

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(\.\d*)?
```

Or more likely:

```
^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(\.\d+)?$
```

`(\.\d+)?` translates to "optionally match an ending period followed by one or more digits"

Notice that I added anchors so that you don't get partial matches.

https://regex101.com/r/muB5JL/1

Comment: Both patterns still match. Sure, the character class won't actually match (or capture) the milliseconds but `.test` will return true because the rest of the pattern matches the input.

Comment: also the dot in `(.\d+)` needs to be escaped.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, thank you. I was just realizing my errors as you commented.